# Loading translations in constructor vs componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I can load chunks of translations inside a component (for example a page or a react-native screen), by doing `i18n.addResources(['en', en, namespace])`.

I instinctively did so in the `componentDidMount` method, which is usually the preferred method for this kind of action and created a small utility component to load my translations files.

```
class NamespaceLoader extends React.Component<NamespaceLoaderProps> {
  public componentDidMount() {
    this.props.resources.map(resource =>
      this.props.i18n.addResources(...resource),
    )
  }

  public render() {
    return this.props.children
  }
}
```

However, by doing so I am waiting for the initial rendering before loading the translations. This triggers messages like `i18next::translator: missingKey fr HomeRecord titleFieldLabel titleFieldLabel` in the console because the children using `<NamespacesConsumer />` also go through an initial render before the translation is loaded.

I found three ways to prevent this behaviour:

- using the `contructor` instead of `componentDidMount` to load the translation. This will block the initial rendering but ensure that all translations are available when it happens.
- passing `wait={true}` to each `<NamespacesConsumer />`, which will not block the initial rendering of the whole screen but requires the developer to remember to pass the prop to each component, since it defaults to false.
- overwriting the `defaultProps` of the `<NamespacesConsumer />` like so:

```
NamespacesConsumer.defaultProps = {
 wait: true,
}
```

What would be the preferred solution to this issue ? It seems to me that using the constructor is not a recommended practice but putting the burden on all developers by requiring them to specify `wait={true}` seems much more error prone.

Answer (score 0):

I found out in [the documentation](https://react.i18next.com/legacy-v9/i18next-instance) that you can default `wait` to `true` when initialising the `i18n` object:

```
i18n
  .use(languageDetector)
  .use(reactI18nextModule)
  .init({
    //...
    react: {
      wait: true,
    },
  })
```

This is probably the best solution to prevent any warning in the console.